# Toggle reveal hide div with Radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am wanting to have a toggler using radio buttons to reveal a div depending on what radio button question they tick.

I have worked out how to get the div to reveal but not how to hide it again ie tick Yes for reveal or if they change their mind tick No to hide again.

Here is my code so far.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <!-- 
    function showMe (it, box) { 
      var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
      document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
    } 
    //--> 
</script>
```

Mark up

```
<h4>Are you an existing customer?</h4>

<input type="radio" name="existing" id="radio" value="Yes" onclick="showMe('existing', this)" /> Yes <input type="radio" name="existing" id="radio" value="No" /> No

<div id="existing">

Please enter your member number <br>
<input type="text" class="loan-app" name="member-number" value="" />

</div>
```

If anyone could help me in the right direction that would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have not attached an `onclick` handler to your **`no`** radio button.

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="existing" id="radio" value="No" onclick="showMe('existing', this)" />
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I did but didnt seem to do anything. I will give it another try. cheers